# google map api, link to URL

Tags: javascript, api, dictionary, google-maps-api-3, interaction

Sorry for asking a simple question I surely can find easily by reading the API docs, but a client just asked me this in general, and I would like to answer him asap.

Situation:
I have a custom map created, with public (or restricted to user) access, where are different markers.

Q1)Is it possible to create markers via the API using e.g. custom data from our database?

Q2)Ist it possible to add a URL to a marker, so that a user clicks on it and gets to a specific site, where he can e.g. vote for this location? (just as an example)

Thanks in advance to everyone, and once more sorry not to look closer by myself

Cheers,
Phil

Comment: One more thing I forgot, this question is as well as for a website as for an native iOS and Android App, too (so more APIs)

Answer (score 0):

Following Function Will Create Marker

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// Standard google maps function
function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.779502, -73.967857);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    TestMarker();
}

// Function for adding a marker to the page.
function addMarker(location) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map
    });
}

// Testing the addMarker function
function TestMarker() {
       CentralPark = new google.maps.LatLng(37.7699298, -122.4469157);
       addMarker(CentralPark);
}
```

For Clicking and URL Use Following Technique

```
var points = [
    ['name1', 59.9362384705039, 30.19232525792222, 12, 'www.google.com'],
    ['name2', 59.941412822085645, 30.263564729357767, 11, 'www.amazon.com'],
    ['name3', 59.939177197629455, 30.273554411974955, 10, 'www.stackoverflow.com']
];

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    ...
    zIndex: place[3],
    url: place[4]
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    window.location.href = this.url;
});
```